# Where are the methods in laravel ColumnDefinition class implemented?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-migrations

To write migrations in laravel, we have different methods to apply them to our `$table` columns. One of them, for example, is `nullable()` which makes that column nullable.

I want to know, where do functions like `nullable()` have been defined. I cannot see anything such as `public function nullable()` in laravel. This must be in one of these classes but I can not find it:

1) `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition`

2) `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Fluent`

3) `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint`

or any other class extended from these or any other trait used in one of these.

Where do these functions have been defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method nullable itself **does not exist**. If you take a look at the `Blueprint` class, the `addColumn` method returns an instance of `ColumnDefinition`.

And `ColumnDefinition` is an empty class which simply extends the `Fluent` class that contains the following `__call` method:

```
/**
 * Handle dynamic calls to the fluent instance to set attributes.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return $this
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    $this->attributes[$method] = count($parameters) > 0 ? $parameters[0] : true;

    return $this;
}
```

Therefore, when you execute `$table->string('name')->nullable();`, it goes into the `__call` because the `nullable` method does not exist and simply saves the `nullable` attribute to `true`. Which also translates to:

```
$this->attributes['nullable'] = true;
```

And then in the `MySqlGrammar` class, it checks if the column is nullable or not:

```
/**
 * Get the SQL for a nullable column modifier.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint  $blueprint
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function modifyNullable(Blueprint $blueprint, Fluent $column)
{
    if (is_null($column->virtualAs) && is_null($column->storedAs)) {
        return $column->nullable ? ' null' : ' not null';
    }
}
```

For more information about `__call`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Answer (score 3):

Modifier functions like `nullable` differs depending on database driver (or Grammar as declared in laravel)

you can find what you want in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\`

for mysql, check `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\MySqlGrammar`